# Trying to run HLDS (Half-Life Dedicated Server) in the Ubuntu CLI - but I keep getting "Unable to initialize Steam."

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, steam

I have a headless linux server running Ubuntu that I ssh into. I run a variety of server programs on it, such as a papermc for Minecraft.

I am trying to set up a HLDS server for Half-Life. I've installed SteamCMD and downloaded both HLDS and Half-Life itself into a new directory in my home folder. My home folder has a "Steam" folder where SteamCMD is installed and a "hlds" folder where the game files are installed.

However, whenever I try to run the server, I get the same error telling me that Steam is not running. How can I fix this?

```
Console initialized.
Using breakpad crash handler
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 70
Forcing breakpad minidump interfaces to load
dlopen failed trying to load:
/home/mrmanager/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so
with error:
/home/mrmanager/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dlopen failed trying to load:
steamclient.so
with error:
steamclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Protocol version 48
Exe version 1.1.2.2/Stdio (valve)
Exe build: 07:36:33 Jul 12 2023 (3378)
STEAM Auth Server
Server IP address 127.0.1.1:27015
[S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; SteamAPI_IsSteamRunning() failed.
dlopen failed trying to load:
steamclient.so
with error:
steamclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; unable to locate a running instance of Steam, or a local steamclient.dll.
FATAL ERROR (shutting down): Unable to initialize Steam.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: So, the obvious question is: Is the file there? The next would be: Do you have all its dependencies? Use `ldd` to find out.

Comment: Check if `ln -s ${HOME}/.local/share/Steam/steamcmd/linux32/steamclient.so ${HOME}/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so` helps.

Comment: I tried that, and it solved the one issue, but I still get this other error: ```steamclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; unable to locate a running instance of Steam, or a local steamclient.dll.
FATAL ERROR (shutting down): Unable to initialize Steam.```